# Python - Unexpected break in for-loop while using Popen

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, subprocess, popen

I need to call one script multiple times but with different arguments. Arguments are stored in argument_list and its list of strings.

```
for argument in argument_list:
    python_command = "python another_script.py --server " + argument
    p = Popen(python_command,shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

The problem is that after one iteration, the script breaks from for loop, even though there are still items in argument_list and there is  no break in loop.

Anyone know why does it happend and how can i solve it? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The problem is most likely with the part of code you **haven't** shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python_command = "python another_script.py --server " + argument
```

The parameters for Popen have to be put in a sequence:

```
python_command = ["python", "another_script.py", "--server", argument]
```

Also, a suggestion: Try to put the Popen statement in a `try ... except`, so that if there is an error, you will get a more detailed explanation about the cause.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Will try to use try ... except. :)